# Use of profanity in code blocks

Tags: discussion, flags

Recently I came across lots of questions in StackOverflow which contain profanity in the codeblocks in questions. So I thought to raise a moderator attention flag to bring it to notice of the mods. I raised two flags for:
[First Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588476/select-value-of-element-wich-is-referenced-by-other) and [Second Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160236/vb-net-unused-local-variable).

My flag for second question got declined on the grounds of: **Moderator found no evidence to support it.** [image]

So my question is, What should we do when we encounter such cases ? Downvote ? Flag ? or Edit ? (Editing in code is not endorsed)

I do respect all the mods and just want to clarify what are the judgments and considerations to use moderation tools like flagging thats all.

**EDIT**

Edit done to question so that no one is offended, really didnt mean to offend any one though. Sorry.

Comment: Don't ask questions in flags.

Comment: Also in the second case you could have suggested an edit. You could try removing the boobs that way too but it would probably be rejected as too radical an edit.

Comment: @PeterJ: Seems like a much less expensive option than surgery though.

Comment: @BoltClock - you and mods are always the wiser one. So I thought to seek some expert advise. #respect.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis- Rewording. Sorry. Really didnt mean to offend.

Comment: Where do you see profanity in this questions? If you see the things noone sees, you are likely to be misunderstood.

Comment: @Р̀СТȢ: _"b\*\*bs"_ in the first one (debatable), and _"C***Sucker"_ used to be in the 2nd one. Especially that second one is just not done.

Comment: Is the first one really offensive ? I do agree that the second one is, but even then, you could just edit it out and leave it at that, as the author probably didn't meant to offend anyone and just happens to use strong language for their comments. Of course, if it's done on purpose (like the other duplicate question) then you should flag it for mod attention.

Comment: wonder why that didnt show up during my search.. seems to answer my queries and i posted this question unnecessarily..

Comment: I'm the autor of one of them, and I'm sorry to include the word "boob" in the example. I'm not a native english speaker and in my examples I usually use words as tuut, lool normally they don't have any problem but this time I haven't seen that its meaning is... well... boob. I think you could let a comment at least.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you raise a moderator flag, you should let the moderator know two things:

1. What the problem is, and
2. What corrective action you believe is appropriate.

Any other communication in a moderator flag is of no relevance.  Moderator flags are not Twitter or an instant messaging system.  Tell the mod what's wrong and what you think they should do to fix it.  That's all.

By all means, if you can fix it yourself, please do so.  Be mindful of the kinds of corrective actions that a moderator can take; moderators can delete abusive posts, for example, but they can't fix voting problems.

If you need guidance, ask a question here.  Don't ask moderators questions in moderator flags; the system is not designed to handle that, and we're too busy dealing with genuine flags.

---

**On the subject of profanity in code blocks...**
The general principle is that you don't change code in a question (for what I hope are obvious reasons), and this is true whether the code contains words that you find offensive or not.  Askers have been known to ask questions about profanity filters; editing the blacklist out of such questions is kinda pointless, and we're not going to disallow such questions just because somebody finds some of the words they contain offensive.

If you flag a question containing "offensive" code, we'll look at it, but the bar is set higher for such redactions (it would have to be deliberately abusive, whereas we require prose to always maintain a professional tone).  We would be more likely to leave a comment telling the OP to "keep it more professional," something you can do yourself.

Comment: exactly @Robert Harvey, thats why i also refrained from doing changes to the code. And thats what i wanted to highlight.

Comment: +1 for the "Dont ask moderators questions in moderators flags..." thats all I wanted to know.. sorry if it was known to all.. I didnt know.. know I ll remember..

Answer (score 21):

First, this is completely broken thinking:

> My flag reporting [x] was declined, therefore [x] must be acceptable!

Profanity is not acceptable anywhere on our network, period. There's an exception made for user profiles, because those generally aren't out in the spotlight anywhere else on the site, but that's it.

What *constitutes* profanity, however, is open to interpretation. I'm not offended by seeing `<boob>` unless of course someone forgets to close the tag later :) I can see why that was declined. There are better names for variables, but I don't see a reason to jump in and make the user change them all in that question, which is essentially what was requested. If you're really bothered by it, *edit it*.

Your *second* question was edited by a moderator to remove the colorful language in the comment. Could be that a mod just declined the wrong flag while working through the queue. Could be that they didn't *see* it (took me a moment too, even after digging through revisions).

Unless a mod declines the flag with a reason like this:

> Declined - [x] that you're reporting is allowed, stop reporting it

... then don't jump into the fallacious assumption that a single (perhaps accidental) action can negate what obviously appears to be common sense. And, *please* don't get so upset if a flag is declined. Moderators are human.

Comment: I am not in anyway upset. I just wanted to highlight a thing that came to notice and wanted to clarify my own judgment of things. And given the amount of traffic and demand it is indeed a tough job for all the mods. So I really dont hold any grudges.

Answer (score 21):

So you found something that bothered you in a post, and instead of:

1. **Editing it out**, or...
2. **Flagging it as offensive** if you felt the post was too shocking to remain, or...
3. **Asking here what you should do** if you were unsure, you opted to...
4. **Write a paragraph apparently containing a question for the moderators.**

That's kinda not what flags are for. Yes, moderators *can* write responses to them, but space is limited and moderator time is even more limited - if they're going to answer a question like that, they're much better off doing so *here*, where it can benefit others. So option #4 is likely to just get your flag declined.

Option #1 is fine. Option #2 is... occasionally valid, for instance if you come across a post that was clearly written merely to offend. Option #3 is *always* useful if you don't know what to do.

Comment: Also, even if they did answer your flag and mark it as helpful, you probably wouldn't even notice because you're not notified... unless you're the kind of person who holds grudges on every last one of your flags and checks your flagging history obsessively, etc.

Comment: @BoltClock i do not hold grudges, but dont you think it is good to see your flagging history atleast once a day to see if your flaggings were correct or not ??? i think its not about obsessiveness its more about knowing if my own knowledge and judgment is at par with the SO policy

Comment: @RicoRicochet: I wasn't talking about you.

Comment: @BoltClock- kinda seemed, my bad.

Comment: There are many posts with f-words in them which are just noise. Should those be edited out? (along with other improvements of the post if needed)

Comment: If you can make a post better, then you should @mixcels.

Answer (score 7):

First, I'm one of the author of the quoted questions. I think that first of all, what must be done is to **comment the question so it can be handle by the author**.

I'm not a native speaker of English (and I think as many of other stackexchange members) so it's possible to us to not see this things so clearly, and a simple comment can make us aware of the problem so we can change it.

If you only flag or downvote without letting a comment (like in my case) the author don't know what happens and the problem will still there.

Comment: First of all, I am also sorry for causing inadvertent problems to all. I just posted a question for clarification on what steps should be taken. Indeed commenting  is the best option it seems for the time being (other than editing on rare cases).

Comment: @RicoRicochet No problem, next time you let a comment and I don't use The Word. But I will be pleased if you remove your down vote.

Comment: hmm.. downvoting because of "bad"-variable name is not justified I think, personally.