# Is using flags to hunt 'unchasteness' a misuse?

Tags: discussion, flags

I've noticed [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284312/use-of-profanity-in-code-blocks) discussion in which the OP was frustrated with mods refusing his flags on posts which he found to contain 'unchaste' words which could cause sinful thoughts by innocent readers.

Those 'unchaste' words weren't even words, but tag names withing XML, where there are numerous reasons why such tag could be called that, none of them could have anything to do with the 'sinful' English word the OP wants to see everywhere.

Is using the flags that waste moderators' time for own crucade agaist evil a misuse?

You know, the 'shameless sinners' have created own proposals on Area51, such as [that](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sex-and-intimacy) or [that](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67058/atheism). The amount of 'sinfull content' will be immense in comparison to all that 'naughty' variable names and if people will be flag-spamming everything, it could be hard for that communities to concentrate on **real** problems.

Comment: The problem with his flags is that they were questions. Besides, most of these cases can be solved by simply suggesting an edit for <2k users, or just editing for >2k. This really didn't need another question, though.

Comment: This seems less like a question and more like an exercise in mocking someone.  You're putting words like "unchaste" and "shameless sinners" in someone else's mouth.  You don't have to be a prick about this shit.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with his flags is that they were questions.

Most of these cases can be solved without getting a mod involved by simply suggesting an edit for <2k users, or just editing for >2k.

Now, it *really* doesn't matter if the "obscene" words are keywords in some xml, or if they're in comments. You just don't use them on SO.

Now, regarding your last line:
*"it could be hard for *those* communities to concentrate on real problems."*

Seriously? Suggested communities about sex and athiesm wouldn't work because their users would be distracted by the content? Let's just keep it at *"I strongly disagree..."* We don't want more "profanity" on SO than there already is, right?

Comment: Do you have any proof, those 'boob' were profanity? And not an acronym or word in other languages? Some people are exaggerating and flagging everything, this is my issue.

Comment: How can you possibly "Prove" something is profanity? It really doesn't matter if the OP tried to sneak in profanity or not. You __Just don't use.__ those words on SO.

Comment: Is there a list of 'forbidden keywords' on SO? Otherwise, anyone could flag any of my post because any of variable names may be profanity in any language. It's an absurd then.

Comment: No, not flag. Edited, maybe. The list is called _"Common sense"_

Comment: @Cerberus exactly this is my issue. The OP lacked the common sense and flagged only because he saw the word that in his language is profane, without a proof the OP was aware of that. And this word was not even a swear word, just a normal dialect word for a body part. I suspect on the Sexuality proposal such words would be more than common. And which hunters will go on flagging spree, if not stopped.

Comment: First of all: Profanity SHOULDN'T be flagged, just edited. ___That___ is the problem in the original question. "Body parts" are completely irrelevant on SO. The sexuality / intimacy proposal is a ___completely___ different site. with ___different___ posting guidelines. Basically, completely unrelated to SO. Who in their right mind would edit a question on sexuality.so that has references to sexual themes, to remove those references? -.-

Comment: @Cerbrus I disagree.  Profanity should be flagged.  If a user has a pattern of profanity, the moderators should be made aware of it.  Of course, editing it is a good idea too.

Comment: I'd flag it if the user reverts the edit. If it's apparent the user is intentionally adding profanity...

Comment: A few months ago, I flagged a post that contained a word that rhymes with trigger.  It could not have been in there unintentionally - I mean, the user had typed this word.  Every speaker of English knows its offensiveness.  And for reasons I'll never understand, the flag was declined.  So I edited the post and removed the word.  What I'm saying is that maybe the moderators agree with you on this - that profanity is not something that should be flagged.  If this is the case, then it's a bit of a shame. I don't want Stack Overflow to be profane; nor can I imagine that anyone else wants it to be.

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that, if you can edit out the profanity, just edit it. Don't flag for something that doesn't require a moderator to get involved.

Comment: If you flag a post where someone is using vulgar or profane language to attack someone else, the moderators will be most happy to step in, @David. Unfortunate words in otherwise-reasonable posts can just be edited out though; sometimes moderators will do this, but it's pure overhead - the flagger could've just done the same. The most frustrating cases arise when someone gets it in their head to search for *word* and blindly flag every instance of it.

Answer (score 4):

Flags are only a misuse if *not* raised in good faith, or if you've been asked to stop raising a particular flag due to a particular set of circumstances. A common example (loosely taken from someone I had to contact privately about their flags)

> "I don't like this question" doesn't always mean it's very low quality and a candidate for immediate deletion.

People flag all *kinds* of stuff as 'spam' that isn't remotely close to unwelcome / unsolicited ads or link planting. However, those flags are in *good faith* - folks honestly felt as if they were reporting something that wasn't right to someone in authority, they just selected the completely wrong reason when doing so.

Moderators can and will decline your flag if they feel that it's (1) without merit or supporting evidence or (2) not something you should be flagging. A *very* common flag to decline is someone reporting a wrong answer - that happens *a lot*. But we have to look at the intent of the users raising the flag - most of them just want to help in some small way, and we're lucky to have them.

With language, there's a subtle difference between:

- *This is likely to offend someone, probably*

and

- *This actually offended **me**, I'm less happy than I was a moment ago after reading it, and this page of the site now embarrasses me*

Try to stick to the second, unless it's a *very* cut and dry case, at which time the first point becomes more of *when* it will offend someone, not *if*.

Part of the reason why Stack Overflow is kept so clean is people keeping an eye out and raising flags, and we've reiterated many times that users should flag something that they really believe to be a problem.

It's only a problem when you create unnecessary work for volunteers, so just watch the results of your flags and see what the mods have to say. If a few get declined, think twice about how you're using that particular flag.

When it comes to flagging, how mods generally respond, how one should interpret their feedback - folks *always* want some black and white guidelines to follow - we're programmers, we like stuff like that. There are just too many human decisions at play here to provide that, and I haven't touched on mistakes that said humans tend to make.

Do what seems right and pay attention to the results, that's all we ask. :) Oh, yeah - remember, mods are there to do what the community *can't*. It's nice to ask yourself "Can I fix this?" before raising a flag for them to do it.

Comment: So even if someone, of course in good faith, starts flagging everything containing 'singular they' as 'bad grammar', it's still OK? Just an example, just similar to the linked Meta question case.

Comment: If they did this, they would be politely asked to stop. If they continued, then they're no longer doing it in good faith.