# For trending, should a post be flagged as inappropriate even if you edit it?

Tags: discussion, flags, rude-or-abusive

I raised a rude or offensive flag for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290730/return-particular-data-at-which-condition-satisfied) that was declined. In it, the OP used some profanity as a debugging statement. Moderator Ryan made a comment in his edit that it was not that big of a deal and slightly modified the output string to remove it (also seems to indicate that I was not the only one to flag it?). This seems to be keeping in good practice, as referenced in this meta post about profanity in code: [Use of profanity in code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284312/use-of-profanity-in-code-blocks)

This is the first time I have encountered this situation though, and I see that the best course would be to just edit it as Ryan did. My question here is a bigger picture one though. Should I flag these posts as offensive anyway as well as edit? Is there a method for tracking adverse flags against a user for trends of abusive or inappropriate posts that would be assisted by having this data? If it is a habitual practice and users just immediately edit, will it ever get addressed?

Comment: Do you *really* think the user should be heavily penalized for the use of a single profane word in a block of code (as opposed to being directed at some other individual)? If you see a pattern of behavior, you could raise a custom moderator flag and explain the problem. If you see this kind of thing one-off, then just edit it and move along. Not everyone views profane language in the same way, and some flexibility here seems reasonable.

Comment: In this case, no one views that word as not profane. As for the possible duplicates, those questions address profanity in posts, not if flagging is useful to moderators for trending purposes.

Comment: I view it as profane, but I also don't view it as something that merits a flogging. If it bothers you, remove it. [My answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351667/366904) starts off specifically by saying you don't need to flag it. Also see the last paragraph.

Comment: If you'd rather not take my word for it, see [Brad Larson's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351257/366904), specifically the first two paragraphs.

Answer (score 7):

If you can fix the post by editing, then no, you shouldn't be flagging the post.  The flags are for posts that *can't* be fixed by editing them (i.e. posts where the entirety of the post is abusive content).

If you're going to fix the problem and then flag the post after the fact there's nothing for the moderator to do, so they're just going to decline your flag.

Comment: Everything about that makes sense, except that I seem to understand there are penalties if you get flagged as offensive or spamming repetitively. Are we doing more harm than good by quietly fixing the problem?

Comment: @SandPiper Those penalties are for posts that are nothing but spam, or nothing but abusive content.  They're not designed for people who use a swear word in a comment that's both not insulting anyone and not in any way essential to the post.  Removing it is fine, because it doesn't add anything, and decracts *a tiny bit* from the quality of the post.  That doesn't make the post abusive.

Comment: @SandPiper if user does use profanity on consistent basis chances are you'll see multiple posts of that kind by regular interaction with the site (i.e. you and the user frequent the same tags). In this case it would be totally appropriate to flag something like "needs moderator intervention: user consistently uses profanity and may benefit with moderator intervention, sample posts (cleaned up already) are {*links to posts*}".